# 1-Element Lists of Functions have a weird Type

Tags: julia

I want to create a Vector of Functions. This works fine, if the vector has multiple elements:

```
[mean, sum]
2-element Vector{Function}:
mean (generic function with 95 methods)
sum (generic function with 30 methods)
```

As expected the type here is `Vector` with element type `Function`.

But if the vector has only one element, this happens:

```
[mean]
1-element Vector{typeof(mean)}:
mean (generic function with 95 methods)
```

Suddenly it is a `Vector` with element type `typeof(mean)`. Is this a bug or am I not smart enough to get the point?

Answer (score 4):

`Function` in Julia is an abstract type:

```
julia> isabstracttype(Function)
true
```

For a given function `foo` calling `typeof(foo)` returns a concrete type:

```
julia> dump(typeof(mean))
typeof(mean) <: Function
```

Since `typeof(foo)` returns a concrete type you can have a vector of union of such types:

```
julia> Union{typeof(mean), typeof(sum)}[mean, sum]
2-element Vector{Union{typeof(sum), typeof(mean)}}:
 mean (generic function with 8 methods)
 sum (generic function with 20 methods)
```

This also means you can create such empty `Vector`:

```
v = Vector{Union{typeof(mean), typeof(sum)}}()
Union{typeof(sum), typeof(mean)}[]
```

and now you can add elements to it:

```
julia> push!(v,mean)
1-element Vector{Union{typeof(sum), typeof(mean)}}:
 mean (generic function with 8 methods)

julia> push!(v,sum)
2-element Vector{Union{typeof(sum), typeof(mean)}}:
 mean (generic function with 8 methods)
 sum (generic function with 20 methods)
```

When you just do `[mean, sum]` Julia tries to find a type that captures both `typeof(mean)` and `typeof(sum)` and you end-up with the abstract `Function` type.

Comment: Specifically, `Function` is the `typejoin` of `typeof(mean)` and `typeof(sum)`.

Comment: This post also shows the syntax for specifying the (concrete or abstract) type of an array literal. It uses `convert` to change the element's types to fit the specified type. In your case, you can write `Function[sum]` to get a `Function` array with only one element

Answer (score 2):

For a function, let's say `mean`, its type is simply `typeof(mean)` and end of the story. So when you only have `mean` in a vector, Julia tries to use the most specific type. When you have two different functions, there's no more common type other than the abstract type `Function`, thus Julia will just fall back to that.

This is analogous to:

```
julia> [1]
1-element Vector{Int64}:
 1

julia> [1, "blah"]
2-element Vector{Any}:
 1
  "blah"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create empty Vector{Function} and push the function to it, or append! another vector of functions to it:

```
using Statistics
funcs  = Vector{Function}()
push!(funcs, mean)
push!(funcs, sum)
append!(funcs, [minimum, maximum])
println(funcs)
```